# How do I skip elements while rendering using jsPDF's affHTML

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I'm using jsPDF to render and save a web page in PDF format.
I'm using something like this.

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'cm', 'A4');

doc.addHTML(
    $('#print')[0],
    function() {
        doc.save('mypdf.pdf');
    });
```

Now I need to disable rendering for some elements in the HTML.
I know that this is possible while using the function 'fromHTML', like this.

```
var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'cm', 'A4');
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#renderme': function(element, renderer) {
        return <<Condition met from any 'renderme' element>>;
    }
};

doc.fromHTML(
    $('#print').[0],
    {
        'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });

doc.output('dataurl');
```

where "Condition met from any 'renderme' element" is clearly pseudocode.
Now my questions is: is it it possibile to achieve the same result using addHTML instead of fromHTML? If yes, how?
Thank you in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the jQuery selectors, filter your content when passing to addHtml.

```
doc.addHTML(
    $('#print .filterSomething')[0],
    function() {
        doc.save('mypdf.pdf');
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, Franklin. It's a good idea, might be useful in some context, but css selectors aren't as flexible as JavaScript-implemented filter.
In any case, I'll study this possibility